# using fgetc with && and || operators in c

Tags: c

I was working on code that merges two files, here's the code :

```
void merge_files(){

FILE *ptf1,*ptf2,*ptf3;
char file_name1[50],file_name2[50],ch,file_name3[50];

int count=0;
printf("please enter the names of the files you want to merge:\n");
printf("file 1:\t");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%[^\n]s",file_name1);
printf("file 2:\t");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%[^\n]s",file_name2);
printf("enter the name of the file you want to merge in:\t");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%[^\n]s",file_name3);
ptf1=fopen(file_name1,"r");
ptf2=fopen(file_name2,"r");
ptf3=fopen(file_name3,"w");
check(ptf1);
check(ptf2);
check(ptf3);
while(!feof(ptf1)&&!feof(ptf2))
{
    ch=0;
    while((ch=fgetc(ptf1))!='\n'&&(ch=fgetc(ptf1))!=EOF)
    {
        fputc(ch,ptf3);
    }
    fprintf(ptf3,"\n");
    while((ch=fgetc(ptf2))!='\n'&&(ch=fgetc(ptf2))!=EOF)
    {
        fputc(ch,ptf3);
    }
    fprintf(ptf3,"\n");
}
fclose(ptf1);
fclose(ptf2);
fclose(ptf3);}
```

it was giving me a garbage output until i realized i should've written the while loop condition like that:

```
while((ch=fgetc(ptf1))!='\n'&&ch!=EOF)
```

my question is what happens when writing the fgetc twice ? does it give ch two values ? how should i use fgetc with & operator ? 
and also i tried using the same code but with || operator , and when using fgetc twice it seemed to work even though it gave me garbage output at the first character of each line, and when using fgetc once it gave me an infinite loop, should i use fgetc like that with || operator ?:

```
while((ch=fgetc(ptf1))!='\n'||(ch=fgetc(ptf1))!=EOF)
```

and like that with && operator ?

```
while((ch=fgetc(ptf1))!='\n'&&ch!=EOF)
```

Comment: You have lot of problems in your code, first flushing stdin is undefined behavior and the fgetc is assigned to ch, isn’t that you need to evaluate with == not with =?

Answer (score 0):

These are very basic/fundamental logic operations in programming.

```
while((ch=fgetc(ptf1))!='\n'&&ch!=EOF)
```

Means read a character, if that character is not a newline and it is not the end-of-file character then execute the loop body.

```
while((ch=fgetc(ptf1))!='\n'||(ch=fgetc(ptf1))!=EOF)
```

Means read a character, if that character is not a newline then execute the loop body. Otherwise, read another character and if it is not the end-of-file character then execute the loop body.

```
while((ch=fgetc(ptf1))!='\n'&&(ch=fgetc(ptf1))!=EOF)
```

Means read a character, if that character is not a newline read another character and if the second one is not the end-of-file character then execute the loop body.